# LinkedOrderedList and LinkedList implementation

Tags: java, linked-list

So I'm supposed to create a program that creates list of animals. The program sorts them out by name and puts them into the list in alphabetical . But every time I click on the "Display Animal" button it shows nothing, I found out it was a problem with the `list.size()` so I changed that to the integer 10 to test it, it displayed but it only shows the first animal added. I'm not sure where the problem is coming from and I'm really confused, here's my code:

This is the LinkeList class

```
package animal;
import exceptions.ElementNotFoundException;
import exceptions.EmptyCollectionException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author Sharon Umute 
 * Comp 139 001B
 * @param <T>
 */
public class LinkedList<T> implements ListADT<T> {

protected int count;
protected SinglyLinkedNode head, tail;
protected int modCount;

/**
 * The LinkedList constructor creates an empty list
*/
public LinkedList(){
    count=0;
    head=tail=null;
    modCount = 0;
}
/**  
 * Removes and returns the head element from this list. 
 * 
 * @return the head element from this list
 */
@Override
public T removeFirst() throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }

    T result=(T) head.getElement();
    head=head.getNext();
    count--;
    modCount++;
    return result;
}

/**  
 * Removes and returns the tail element from this list. 
 *
 * @return the tail element from this list
 */
@Override
public T removeLast() throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }

    T result=(T) tail.getElement();
    tail=tail.getNext();
    count--;
    modCount++;
    return result;
}

/**  
 * Removes and returns the specified element from this list. 
 *
 * @param targetElement the target element
 * @return the target element
 */
@Override
public T remove(T targetElement) throws EmptyCollectionException, ElementNotFoundException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }

    boolean found = false;
    SinglyLinkedNode<T> previous = null;
    SinglyLinkedNode<T> current = head;

    while (current != null && !found)
        if (targetElement.equals(current.getElement()))
            found = true;
        else
        {
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }

    if (!found)
        throw new ElementNotFoundException("LinkedList");

    if (size() == 1)  // only one element in the list
        head = tail = null;
    else if (current.equals(head))  // target is at the head 
        head = current.getNext();
    else if (current.equals(tail))  // target is at the tail
    {
        tail = previous;
        tail.setNext(null);
    }
    else  // target is in the middle
        previous.setNext(current.getNext());

    count--;
    modCount++;
    return current.getElement();


}

/**  
 * Returns a reference to the head element in this list. 
 *
 * @return a reference to the head element in this list
 */
@Override
public T first() throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }

    T result=(T) head.getElement();
    return result;
}

/**  
 * Returns a reference to the tail element in this list. 
 *
 * @return a reference to the tail element in this list
 */
@Override
public T last() throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }

    T result=(T) tail.getElement();
    return result;
}

/**  
 * Returns true if this list contains the specified target element. 
 *
 * @param target the target that is being sought in the list
 * @return true if the list contains this element
 */
@Override
public boolean contains(T target) throws EmptyCollectionException {
    if(isEmpty()){
        throw new EmptyCollectionException("list");
    }
    for(T result:this){
        if(result.equals(target)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**  
 * Returns true if this list contains no elements. 
 *
 * @return true if this list contains no elements
 */
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return(head==null);
}

 /**  
 * Returns the number of elements in this list. 
 *
 * @return the integer representation of number of elements in this list
 */
@Override
public int size() {
    return count;
}

/**  
 * Returns an iterator for the elements in this list. 
 *
 * @return an iterator over the elements in this list
 */
@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new LinkedListIterator();
}


private class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<T>
    {
        private int iteratorModCount;  // the number of elements in the collection
        private SinglyLinkedNode<T> current;  // the current position


    /**
     * Sets up this iterator using the specified items.
     *
     * @param collection  the collection the iterator will move over
     * @param size        the integer size of the collection
     */
    public LinkedListIterator()
    {
        current = head;
        iteratorModCount = modCount;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this iterator has at least one more element
     * to deliver in the iteration.
     *
     * @return  true if this iterator has at least one more element to deliver
     *          in the iteration
     * @throws  ConcurrentModificationException if the collection has changed
     *          while the iterator is in use
     */
    public boolean hasNext() throws ConcurrentModificationException
    {
        if (iteratorModCount != modCount) 
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

        return (current != null);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next element in the iteration. If there are no
     * more elements in this iteration, a NoSuchElementException is
     * thrown.
     *
     * @return the next element in the iteration
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iterator is empty
     */
    public T next() throws ConcurrentModificationException
    {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        T result = current.getElement();
        current = current.getNext();
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * The remove operation is not supported.
     * 
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the remove operation is called
     */
    public void remove() throws UnsupportedOperationException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

}
```

This is the LinkedOrderedList class:

```
    package animal;
/**
 * @author Sharon Umute 
 * Comp 139 001B
 * @param <T>
 */
public class LinkedOrderedList<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements OrderedListADT<T>{


    /**
     * Creates an empty list.
     */
    public LinkedOrderedList()
    {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Adds the specified element to this list at the proper location
     *
     * @param element the element to be added to this list
     */
    @Override
    public void add(T element) {
        SinglyLinkedNode<T> node =new SinglyLinkedNode<>(element);
        SinglyLinkedNode<T> previous=null;
        SinglyLinkedNode<T> current=head;
        Animal animal;
        Animal animal2;
        int result;
        if(isEmpty()){
            tail = head = node;
        }else{
            int i=0;
            while( i<this.size()){
                animal=(Animal) current.getElement();
                animal2=(Animal) node.getElement();
                result=animal.getName().compareTo(animal2.getName());
                if((result==-1)&&(current!=head)&&(current!=tail)){
                    previous=current;
                    current=current.getNext();
                    i++;
                }else if((result==1)&&(current!=head)&&(current!=tail)){
                    previous.setNext(node);
                }else if((result==0)&&(current!=head)&&(current!=tail)){
                    i++;
                }
                if((current==head)||((size()==1)&&(result==1))){
                    node.setNext(head);
                    head=node;
                }else if((current==tail)||((size()==1)&&(result==-1))){
                    tail.setNext(node);
                    tail=node;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the GUI called SimpleGUI, i'm not allowed to alter anything here except `actionPerformed` So that's the only part displaying:

```
    @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) throws NullPointerException {
    Object object = ev.getSource();
        if (object == addReptileButton) {
            try {
                useA= new Reptile(namePanel.getText(), weightPanel.getValue(), 
                        agePanel.getValue(),reptileLengthPanel.getValue());
            } catch (InvalidNameException | InvalidWeightException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SimpleGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                        null, ex);
            }

            try{
                list.add(useA);
            }catch(EmptyCollectionException|NullPointerException ec){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The List isEmpty", 
                        "Input Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }else if (object == addMammalButton) {
            try {
                useA= new Mammal(namePanel.getText(), weightPanel.getValue(), 
                        agePanel.getValue(),mammalColorPanel.getText());
            } catch (InvalidNameException | InvalidWeightException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SimpleGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                        null, ex);
            }
            try{
                list.add(useA);
            }catch(EmptyCollectionException|NullPointerException  ec){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The List is Empty", 
                        "Input Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }else if (object == RemoveFirst) { 
            try{
                Animal current = (Animal) list.removeFirst();
            }catch(EmptyCollectionException|NullPointerException  ec){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The List is Empty", 
                        "Input Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }else if (object == RemoveLast) {
            try{
                Animal current = (Animal) list.removeLast();
            }catch(EmptyCollectionException|NullPointerException  ec){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The list is Empty", 
                        "Input Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else if (object == displayAnimalsButton) {
            verifyArea.setText(" ");
            try{
                for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
                    Animal result = (Animal) list.removeFirst();
                    verifyArea.append(result.toString());
                    list.add(result);
                }
            }catch(EmptyCollectionException ex){
                verifyArea.append(" ");
            }
        }

    }
```

Could someone please tell me what the problem is here and how to fix it. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I think it's unlikely anyone will want to wade through all this code. I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to see what it going wrong.

Comment: "so I changed that to the integer 10 to test it, it displayed but it only shows the first animal added" . how many animals you are expecting ? can you add an  linked list list 'n' animals and see where you are going wrong. not sure why you are calling "removeFirst" when your operation says "Display".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but the way you are displaying the list is a bit crazy.  If anything is wrong with your implementation of either size, add or remove, then each time you attempt to display the list you could trash it.

A better way would be to use the list iterator.

But more generally, you NEED TO learn how to use the Debugger in your IDE.  Using a debugger is a basic skill that every programmer needs to master.  A programmer who can't debug code, is basically useless to an employer.

The other thing you need to learn is how to write Unit Tests.